# How do I position a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered,
  minimum height=4em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
  % Place nodes
  \node [block] (I/O) {I/O};
  \node [block, below of = I/O] (CPU1) {CPU};
  \node [block, right of = CPU1] (CPU2) {CPU};
  \node [block, below of = CPU1] (Mem) {Memory};

  \draw [--] (I/O) -- (CPU1);
  \draw [--] (I/O) -| (CPU2);
  \draw [--] (CPU1) -- (Mem);
  \draw [--] (CPU2) |- (Mem);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Which yields

[image]

How do I move the center CPU node (CPU1) to the left and replicate CPU2? Sorry if that isn't more clear, Basically just move the middle node to line up the right edge with the left edges of I/O and Memory.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's easier if you use the `calc` library and change the commands for the positioning a bit.

By the way, I suggest you name the nodes with simple references, typing `I/O` gets tedious after a bit. Use lowercase, avoid extra symbols preferring letters and/or numbers only.

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}   
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered,
  minimum height=4em]

\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance = 2cm, auto]
  % Place nodes
    \node [block] (io) {I/O};
    \node [block, below =2cm of io] (mem) {Memory};
    \node [block, anchor=east] (CPU1) at ($(io.south west)!.5!(mem.north west)$) {CPU};
    \node [block, anchor=west] (CPU2) at ($(io.south east)!.5!(mem.north east)$) {CPU}; 

    \draw (io) -| (CPU1);
    \draw (io) -| (CPU2);
    \draw (CPU1) |- (mem);
    \draw (CPU2) |- (mem);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Short addendum: The same effect can be achieved without the `calc` library syntax, e.g. `\path (io.south west) -- node[block,left] (CPU1) {CPU} (mem.north west)      (io.south east) -- node[block,right] (CPU2)  {CPU} (mem.north east);`

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution using:

- `positioning` TikZ library (new and better syntax: `left=of ...`)
- `node distance` with two lengths (to use Manhattan distance)
- `on grid` option to position nodes relatively to their centers
- `\tikszet` instead of `\tikzstyle`

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm and 2cm,on grid]
  % Define block styles
  \tikzset{
    block/.style={
      rectangle, draw,
      text width=5em, text centered,
      minimum height=4em,
    }
  }

  % Place nodes
  \node [block] (I/O) {I/O};
  \node [block, below left= of I/O] (CPU1) {CPU};
  \node [block, below right= of I/O] (CPU2) {CPU};
  \node [block, below right= of CPU1] (Mem) {Memory};

  \draw (I/O) -| (CPU1);
  \draw (I/O) -| (CPU2);
  \draw (CPU1) |- (Mem);
  \draw (CPU2) |- (Mem);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```